# changing frames when using auto layouts

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am using auto layouts and i want to access controls programmatically with orientation from portrait to landscape,

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        UIButton *btnLogin = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
        btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(300, 150, 437, 91);


    }
    else
    {
        UIButton *btnLogin = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
        btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(162, 540, 437, 91);
    }

}
```

the debugger goes into code but the frame of button doesn't change.Is this possible with auto layouts?

Comment: You may only change frame in case of auto-layout with changing auto-layout constraint

Answer (score 0):

This article explains very well the layout process when auto-layout is involved: http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html

Basically, on every layout loop (don't forget that all view layout is not a continuous process but a discrete one based on the main thread run loop), when auto-layout is turned on the system evaluates all constraints and then apply them to build the final layout.

Your only change required to override this mechanism is to change your `layoutSubviews` view controller implementation by calling "super" first and then updating your frames after.

However this is not considered good practice and you should only use it when you cannot achieve the same effect using auto-layout or because doing that with auto-layout would impact on performance. So use it sparingly. This technique is also explained here: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/03/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-auto-layout/

Looking at your example, it seems that you're trying to place the button in a complete different position between iPad portrait and landscape orientations so probably you cannot use auto layout, but consider that you can still link the top and leading edges of your button to a reference (e.g. the view controller view) and then update these constrains: if no other objects are constrained to this button the operation is not computationally intensive and you can still use auto layout.